# OrderedDict() returned from dataset.variable

Tags: python-2.7, netcdf4

I want to parse NetCDF file using NETCDF4 and Python
My code is :

```
 >>> from netCDF4 import Dataset
    >>> dataset = Dataset('data.nc') 
    >>> print dataset.variables
     OrderedDict()
```

Why OrderedDict() is returned ?
Actually the Netcdf format is new for me here is a part of it :

```
group: PRODUCT {
  dimensions:
    scanline = 289 ;
    ground_pixel = 215 ;
    corner = 4 ;
    time = 1 ;
    layer = 50 ;
  variables:
    int scanline(scanline) ;
        scanline:units = "1" ;
```

So I want to access the variables and tried everything in my mind but all failed..
One of my trails is :

```
>print dataset.variables.keys()
 []
```

But it returned []
So any idea how to access these variables ?
Thanks in advance,
Hala

Comment: I got the answer I used print dataset["PRODUCT"].variables['ground_pixel'][0]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Dataset.renameGroup
The answer is :
print dataset["PRODUCT"].variables['ground_pixel'][0]

Have a nice day